# Loading image from gallery by local URL (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, image, nsurl, phasset

I’ve encountered a strange behavior:

An imagePicker returns a PHAsset, and I do the Following and manage to present an imageView with image from the data:

```
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()) { (input, _) in
    let url = input?.fullSizeImageURL

    let  imgV = UIImageView()

    let test_url = URL(string: (url?.absoluteString)!)

    print("><><><^^^><><>\(test_url)")
    //prints: ><><><^^^><><>Optional(file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/107APPLE/IMG_7242.JPG)
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: test_url! as URL)
    imgV.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
    imgV.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    att.imageLocalURL = url?.absoluteString//// saving the string to use in the other class

    imgV.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

    self.view.addSubview(imgV) /// just to test that the file exists and can produce an image
```

However when I do the following in another class:

```
if((NSURL( string: self.attachment.imageLocalURL! ) as URL!).isFileURL)// checking if is Local URL
    {


        let test_url = URL(string:  self.attachment.imageLocalURL!) // reading the value stored from before
        print("><><><^^^><><>\(test_url)")
        //prints :><><><^^^><><>Optional(file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/107APPLE/IMG_7242.JPG)
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: test_url! as URL)
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)

    }
```

The data is nil! What am I doing wrong, the String for URL is identical in both cases!

Comment: Did you try with breakpoints and see step-by-step where it produces an unexpected result?

Comment: Class A: url_a -> string_a -> data -> image, but Class B:  string_a -> data -> nil, that is the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`PHAsset` objects should be accessed via the `PHImageManager` class. If you want to load the image synchronously I recommend you do something like this:

```
func getImage(assetUrl: URL) -> UIImage?  {
        let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [assetUrl], options: nil)

        guard let result = asset.firstObject else {
            return nil
        }
        var assetImage: UIImage?
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.isSynchronous = true
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: result, targetSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill, options: options) { image, info in
            assetImage = image
        }

        return assetImage
    }
```

You could even write a UIImageView extension to load the image directly from a PHAsset url.

Answer (score 0):

var images:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray() //hold the fetched images

```
func fetchPhotos ()
{
   images = NSMutableArray()
   //totalImageCountNeeded = 3
   self.fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(0)
}

func fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(index:Int)
{
    let status : PHAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if status == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized
    {
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.synchronous = true

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: true)]

    if let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions)
    {
        if fetchResult.count > 0
        {
                imgManager.requestImageForAsset(fetchResult.objectAtIndex(fetchResult.count - 1 - index) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSizeMake(self.img_CollectionL.frame.size.height/3, self.img_CollectionL.frame.size.width/3), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, _) in
                //self.images.addObject(image!)
                if image != nil
                {
                    self.images.addObject(image!)
                }
                if index + 1 < fetchResult.count && self.images.count < 20 //self.totalImageCountNeeded
                {
                    self.fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(index + 1)
                }
                else
                {
                }
            })
            self.img_CollectionL.reloadData()

        }
    }
    }
}
```